# ViewPager, FragmentStatePagerAdapter, ListFragment separate list data for each Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with a dynamic number of pages in it. Each of these pages needs to read from a db and display the dataset for that page.

I compare the currently selected pages title with the first value in the db "username" to check if the data is relevant for that page.

My fragments though dont display the data correctly. Im trying to set an arrayAdapter in the onCreateView, but its not called on the creation of each fragment. In my test case, I have three fragments, user1, user2, user3. onCreateView is called on user1 originally, then is only called again when I swipe back to user2, and never again for user1 or user3.

I need to be able to set the arrayAdapter for each fragment specifically because each one will have a different array of values to display.

**PagerAdapter**

```
   public class ExamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements TitleProvider{

        private Map<Integer, UserFragment> mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, UserFragment>();

        public ExamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return user;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new UserFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);        
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public String getTitle(int pos) {
            return "@"+users[pos].getName();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {              
            mPageReferenceMap.remove(Integer.valueOf(position));
        }
    }
```

**UserFragment**

```
public class UserFragment extends ListFragment {
      Context ctx;
      View v;
      Button mAddEntry;
      static int p; 
      static ArrayList<String> entryArray;

       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ctx = container.getContext();
            if (v != null) 
                return v;

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fragment, container, false);
            mAddEntry = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.entry_b);
            mAddEntry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("pos", p);
                    Intent mi = new Intent(v.getContext(), EntryAdd.class);
                    mi.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(mi);
                }
            });             
            updateUserFrag();
            return v;      
       }     

       public void updateUserFrag () {         
             entryArray = new ArrayList<String>();
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(ctx);
             db.open();
             Cursor c = db.getAllEntries();
             try {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    if (c.getString(0).equals(MainActivity.users[p].getName())) {
                        sb.append(c.getString(1));
                        entryArray.add(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
             } catch (Exception e) {}
             c.close();
             db.close();

             ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entryArray);
             setListAdapter(a);
       }

}
```

Basically, I just need a method I can use to give each fragment its data when its created. onCreateView() doesnt get called for each fragment, so thats no use for me.

**UPDATE**
I think I've almost got it, but I cant figure out this last part. Im using TitlePageIndicators onPageSelected method to send data to my fragment handler.

```
   TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager, 0);
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onPageSelected(int position) {
              Message msg = UserFragment.handy.obtainMessage(); 
              Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
              b.putInt("m", 0); 
              b.putInt("p", position); 
              b.putStringArrayList("e", updateUserFrag(position));
              msg.setData(b); 
              UserFragment.handy.handleMessage(msg);                 
         }
```

Handler

```
   static Handler handy = new Handler() { 
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
            int p = msg.getData().getInt("p"); 
            int m = msg.getData().getInt("m"); 
            ArrayList<String> e = msg.getData().getStringArrayList("e");

            switch (m) { 
                case 0: 
                    Log.d("HANDLER", Integer.toString(p));
                    for (int i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
                        //Log.d("ENTRY", e.get(i));
                    }
                break; 
             } 
        } 
   };
```

The problem is that by the time the handler is called, the Arrayadapter has already been set, and I can find a way to trigger a refresh of that data.

Comment: have you tried overriding onActivityCreated(Bundle b)

Comment: same problem. its called on the first page, then the second, and from then on, only the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          Message msg = UserFragment.handy.obtainMessage(); 
          Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
          b.putInt("m", 0); 
          b.putInt("p", position); 
          b.putStringArrayList("e", updateUserFrag(position));
          msg.setData(b); 
          UserFragment.handy.handleMessage(msg);                 
     }

   public ArrayList<String> updateUserFrag (int p) {           
         entryArray = new ArrayList<String>();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
         db.open();
         Cursor c = db.getAllEntries();
         try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                if (c.getString(0).equals(users[p].getName())) {
                    sb.append(c.getString(1));
                    entryArray.add(sb.toString());
                }
            }
         } catch (Exception e) {}
         c.close();
         db.close();
        return entryArray;           
   }
```

UserFragment

```
public class UserFragment extends ListFragment {
      Context ctx;
      View v;
      Button mAddEntry;
      static int p; 
      static ArrayList<String> entryArray;
      static ArrayAdapter<String> a;

       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ctx = container.getContext();
            if (v != null) 
                return v;

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fragment, container, false);
            mAddEntry = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.entry_b);
            mAddEntry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("pos", p);
                    Intent mi = new Intent(v.getContext(), EntryAdd.class);
                    mi.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(mi);
                }
            });    
            updateUserFrag(p);
            return v;      
       }     

       public void updateUserFrag (int p) {        
             entryArray = new ArrayList<String>();
             a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, entryArray);
             setListAdapter(a);
       }

       static Handler handy = new Handler() { 
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
                int p = msg.getData().getInt("p"); 
                int m = msg.getData().getInt("m"); 
                ArrayList<String> e = msg.getData().getStringArrayList("e");

                switch (m) { 
                    case 0: 
                        Log.d("HANDLER", Integer.toString(p));
                        entryArray.clear();
                        for (int i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
                            entryArray.add(e.get(i));
                        }
                        a.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break; 
                 } 
            } 
       };      
}
```